# How can the result of collect() be limited to a certain number of items?

Tags: rust

Consider the following:

```
fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let even = input.iter().filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0).collect::<Vec<&i32>>();

    for x in &even {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

This outputs `2 4 6 8 10` (as expected). However, what if I only wanted the first 3 items? Is it possible to limit the return value of `collect` somehow, without collecting everything first and throwing away some of the items afterwards?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Iterator::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take):

```
fn main() {
    let input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    let even = input
        .iter()
        .filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0)
        .take(3)
        .collect::<Vec<&i32>>();

    for x in &even {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!